# C method should call itself recursive twice, but doesn't seem to do it

Tags: c, recursion

I'm relatively new to C and I've got the following problem:
I'm trying to build a [Satsolver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) using the DPLL alogrithm.
I guess you don't have to know the algorithm or problem to answer my question.

The DPLL method trys some stuff and calls itself twice at the end like this:

```
return (DPLL(newarray[0], variables, &newclauses))
        || (DPLL(newarray2[0], variables, &newclauses2));
```

The idea of it is, that at the end there are two new arrays. One gets a new value, the other one gets the negated value.

My problem is: The algorithm doesn't seem to check the second method call

```
DPLL(newarray2[0], variables, &newclauses2
```

Because the whole algorithm returns 0, if

```
(DPLL(newarray[0], variables, &newclauses2)
```

is 0. It's fine that it returns 1, if the first call is 1.

The DPLL is called from my main method like this:

```
    if (DPLL(phi, variables, &claues))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "SATISFIABLE");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "UNSATISFIABLE");
    }
```

Is it even possible in c to do the recursive calls it like this?

Comment: if you use | instead of || will it still do short-circuit eval?

Comment: Hey! That gives me the same result

Comment: So it works? Good. The || is a logical or but does short circuit. The | can be a bitwise or OR a logical or without short circuit

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The problem stays exactly the same

Comment: Dang it. Well thanks for trying it. I dont know much about c but thats the way it can work in c#/java (im pretty sure)

Answer (score 3):

The reason the second call may not happen is because of [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If the first call returns a true value the entire expression is true and so there is no need to evaluate the second call. If you want to guarantee that both are called you could do this:

```
int r1 = DPLL(newarray[0], variables, &newclauses);
int r2 = DPLL(newarray2[0], variables, &newclauses2);
return r1 || r2;
```

In this case both calls are completed before any short circuiting happens in the return. However, short circuit evaluation is a good optimization in the example you gave.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is short-circuiting - in an expression of type `a || b`, `b` is only evaluated if `a` is false. This is mandated by the C++ rules (the standard).

In your case, if the first call to `DPLL` returns `true`, the second call won't executed.

You'll need to refactor your code as:

```
bool a1 = DPLL(newarray[0], variables, &newclauses);
bool a2 = DPLL(newarray2[0], variables, &newclauses2);
return a1 || a2;
```

Comment: That's fine. The problem is, that it returns 0 if the first DPLL call is 0.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers!

But that doesn't quite do it. It seems, that the algorithm just goes to the full depth of the first one, whatever that one is. I tried to do it like you proposed, but it gave me a 0, where a 1 was expected. Funny thing is that when I turn around the function calls, so that the call that would return a 1 comes first, it works. But then it doesn't work for ohter files anymore.